# How to open green chest in Perdida?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

There is a green chest on top of the building right opposite cat's cradle in Perdida. Where is the spot to shoot it down using Swaine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble here too. Move back, toward the peddler, and shoot it with Swaine's lockgun.

Comment: OK! Finally found the spot, right in front of the peddler. I always thought that it was for speaking to the peddler! After tiptoeing around I found out it was actually for the chest.